# Spring Boot : log4j2.xml next to app.jar not read in production environment

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I'm new to Spring Boot.

Under 'resources' there are 2 files :

```
-- resources
    -- application.properties
    -- log4j2.xml
```

In development environment everything works fine.

In production environment, I copy both files and put them next to the app.jar :

```
  -- app_folder
        -- my-app.jar
        -- application.properties
        -- log4j2.xml
```

When I start the my-app.jar, :

- application.properties is read from app_folder, as intended
- log4j2.xml is read from 'resources', the one under app_folder is ignored

Shouldn't it work this way out of the box ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was putting a file named

```
name-of-my-spring-boot-jar-file.conf
```

in the same directory as the jar file itself.
Content of conf file :

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/home/<user>/log4j2.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you assume it works that way?

It is true that according to its [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) Spring Boot will detect `application.properties` correctly if it is placed in the same directory as the jar file.

That being said `log4j2.xml` is not read by Spring Boot but by Log4J2 Framework and according to its [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) that framework oly looks for files on the classpath.

If the file is elsewhere you need to specify the path like this:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml -jar my-app.jar
```

Edit:

> my-app.jar is an executable, so I don't invoke the 'java' command when starting my-app.

Yes you do. Even if you're invoking it from a GUI (eg. double clicking in Explorer in Windows) it still runs `java -jar my-app.jar` under the hood.

> Isn't the same folder the app.jar resides in considered classpath ?

Again, why would you assume that it is?

In the Java documentation ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) for Java 8) in section `Folders and Archive Files` it clearly says that if the classes are stored in a jar, then the classpath includes only stuff from the jar (although in case of Spring Boot due to the custom classloader it also includes jars embedded in the jar, whch would normally not be the case - see [Executable Jar Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html)).

You really should read the documentation (or at least relevant parts of it) before attempting to use any framework/library/programming language you have not used before - it will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: my-app.jar is an executable, so I don't invoke the 'java' command when starting my-app. Isn't the same folder the app.jar resides in considered classpath ?